# Geopandas polygon to line

Tags: python, plot, postgis, spatial, geopandas

I am new to geopandas and would like to plot only the outline of a polygon, similar to the function `ST_Boundary()` in PostGIS

I have a geodataframe `states` containing polygons for each state

```
states = counties.dissolve(by='STATEFP')
```

When I subset by one state, I am able to plot that state:

```
states.loc[states.index.isin(['06'])]['geometry']
```

I am only interested in the outline but it is not clear in the documentation how to convert a polygon to line geometry however.  Is there a useful method in `geopandas` or another spatial library that might help in converting a polygon to a linestring?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get boundary as

```py
states.boundary
```

Alternatively, if you want only exterior boundary you get it as

```py
states.exterior
```

Those give you new `GeoSeries` with line geometry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like .exterior returns a geometry of type 'linear ring', whereas .boundary returns a geometry of type 'linestring' - this may be important when it comes to writing the line geometries to file - I had issues writing 'linear ring' to GPKG and SHP but it worked for 'linestring'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Best to add this as a comment to the accepted answer. This is not a solution.